# Refactoring Function for json parser Swift

Tags: json, swift

I have a function i use for parsing json which works fine, however instead of me repeating things, i am looking for a way to refactor it such that i can pass any of my model object to the function's closure and it should still perform the same way.

This are the list of object i have to pass into the fun

1. Video
2. Event
3. Trend
4. News

The function below takes Video as parameter for the closure

```
func fetchFeedForUrlString(urlString: String, completion: @escaping     ([Video]) -> ()){

    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url as URL) { (data, responseUrl, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil{
            print("Unable to fetch data\(error)")
            return
        }

        if let wrappedData = data,
            let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: wrappedData, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]{

            if let results = json?["data"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]{
                let videos = results.map({return Video(dictionary: $0)})

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(videos)
                }
            }

        }

    }.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's a bit hard to tell you how to refactor it, but firstly I'd say you should declare a `JSONDecodable` protocol, or kind of. In this way you can define a protocol that describes object that can be initialized by a JSON.

```
protocol JSONDecodable {
    init?(_ json: [String: Any])
}
```

The conform the `Video` class to `JSONDecodable` protocol

```
class Video: JSONDecodable {
    init?(_ json: [String: Any]) {
        // your init code here. It can return nil in case the JSON is invalid
    }
}
```

Then you can use Swift generics to create a generic function

```
func fetchFeedForUrlString<T: JSONDecodable>(urlString: String, completion: @escaping     ([T]) -> ()){

    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url as URL) { (data, responseUrl, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil{
            print("Unable to fetch data\(error)")
            return
        }

        if let wrappedData = data,
            let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: wrappedData, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]{

            if let results = json?["data"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]{
                let videos = results.flatMap({return T($0)})

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(videos)
                }
            }

        }

    }.resume()
}
```

Be careful because in this way you have to declare two different functions for parsing a set of `JSONDecodable` objects or only one.

To use it, simply write this

```
Instance.fetchFeedForUrlString(...) { (videos as [Video]) in
    /// your code here
}
```

Writing `(videos as [Video])` you tell the compiler that the `T` parameter is a `Video` type, otherwise it cannot infer the type somewhere else.
This implementation isn't the best and it's still improvable.

Comment: I tried it, i am getting something, like  In argument type '([Video]) -> ()', 'Video' does not conform to expected type 'JSONDecodable'

Comment: You should make conform the `Video` to `JSONDecodable` protocol

Comment: But you said it isn't the best option, is there any down side to the approach?

Comment: Check out this talk: https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E01-networking This is an approach I would prefer @SimpiMind